# Get Users who login into the system Today From A.M to P.M

Tags: postgresql, symfony, datetime, doctrine, query-builder

I have an entity LoginHistory that saves user's login and logout time. I am building a query to get users who login today.

```
 id | user_id |      login_at       |      logout_at      |     created_at      
----+---------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------
 44 |      38 | 2016-01-18 02:02:26 |                     | 2016-01-18 02:02:26
 45 |      38 |                     | 2016-01-18 02:02:35 | 2016-01-18 02:02:35
 51 |      38 | 2016-01-18 14:33:10 |                     | 2016-01-18 14:33:10
 52 |      38 |                     | 2016-01-18 14:33:24 | 2016-01-18 14:33:24
```

Now on the Twig template i have to display the user login and logout time of one session at each line.

i worte this querybuilder

```
$loggedInUsers= $this->createQueryBuilder('logs')
            ->where('logs.user =:userID')
            ->andwhere('logs.loginAt >= :todayStartDate or logs.logoutdAt <= :todayEndDate')
            ->setParameter('userID', $userID)
            ->setParameter('todayStartDate', '2016-01-18 00:00:00')
            ->setParameter('todayEndDate', '2016-01-18 23:59:59')
            ->orderBy('logs.createdAt', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery() 
            ->getResult();
```

and on twig the code is below;

```
  {% for data in login_history %}
Login At {{ data.loginat|date('d M Y h:i:s A') }} &nbsp;&nbsp; & Logout at {{ data.logoutdAt|date('d M Y h:i:s A') }} <br />
{% endfor %}
```

and it output as;

```
Login At 18 Jan 2016 03:17:08 PM    & Logout at 13 Jan 2016 05:27:46 PM 
Login At 18 Jan 2016 03:17:08 PM    & Logout at 15 Jan 2016 11:27:35 AM 
Login At 18 Jan 2016 02:02:26 AM    & Logout at 18 Jan 2016 03:17:08 PM 
Login At 18 Jan 2016 03:17:08 PM    & Logout at 18 Jan 2016 02:02:35 AM 
Login At 18 Jan 2016 02:33:10 PM    & Logout at 18 Jan 2016 03:17:08 PM 
Login At 18 Jan 2016 03:17:08 PM    & Logout at 18 Jan 2016 02:33:24 PM
```

Instead it should return;

```
Login At 18 Jan 2016 02:02:26 AM    & Logout at 13 Jan 2016 02:02:35 AM 
Login At 18 Jan 2016 02:33:10 PM    & Logout at 13 Jan 2016 02:33:24 PM
```

I don't know where I am getting wrong...

Comment: I'm not a pro in SQL, but ''logs.loginAt >= :todayStartDate or logs.logoutdAt <= :todayEndDate'' shouldn't be AND instead of OR, since you want datas between 2 ranges?

Comment: @BartBartoman When used `AND` Operator it returns no data.

Comment: Maybe because your range aren't correct? Corret me if I'm wrong, but login at 18 Jan 2016 and logout at 13 Jan, according to your 2 final lines of what you said you want to get.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will find all users that logged in today as well as any user that logged out any time previously up until the end of today.

If you updated your query like...

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('logs');

$logHistory = $qb
    ->where('logs.user =:userID')
    // and where multiple "OR's"
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->orX(
        // logs.loginAt BETWEEN :todayStartDate AND :todayEndDate
        $qb->expr()->between('logs.loginAt', ':todayStartDate', ':todayEndDate'),
        // logs.logoutAt BETWEEN :todayStartDate AND :todayEndDate
        $qb->expr()->between('logs.logoutAt', ':todayStartDate', ':todayEndDate')
    ))
    ->setParameter('userID', $userID)
    ->setParameter('todayStartDate', new \DateTime('today'))
    ->setParameter('todayEndDate', new \DateTime('tomorrow - 1 second'))
    ->orderBy('logs.createdAt', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery() 
    ->getResult();
```

That would give you all users that have either logged in or out today but only in the format of your original table (1 record per row as opposed to aggregated down to a log in a log out per row).

You could do the following to aggregate your results (It's not pretty and I'm not at all happy with it).

```
$userLog = array();

foreach ($logHistory as $log) {
    if (null !== $loginAt = $log->getLoginAt()) {
        $userLog[] = array(
            'userId'    => $log->getUserId(),
            'loginAt'   => $loginAt,
            'logoutAt'  => null,
        );
    }

    if (null !== $logoutAt = $log->getLogoutAt()) {
        $updated = false;

        // reverse the array as logs at the start are more likely to be complete
        foreach (array_reverse($userLog) as $k => &$row) {
            if ($log->getUser() === $row['userId'] && null === $row['logoutAt']) {
                $row['logoutAt'] = $logoutAt;
                $updated = true;

                break;
            }
        }

        // for logout events without a login, i.e. users that logged in yesterday
        if (false === $updated) {
            $userLog[] = array(
                'userId'    => $log->getUserId(),
                'loginAt'   => null,
                'logoutAt'  => $logoutAt,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This query will not give OP the desired result.

Comment: Yeah, I've just realised that. I'm thinking it would need some sort of processing after as it can't really be grouped....

Comment: Yes, it works, but when i pass this, `->setParameter('todayStartDate', new \Datetime('today')) ->setParameter('todayEndDate', new \Datetime('today'))` it returns null.

Comment: That would be because they are the same time, today at 00:00:00.

Comment: Would it help to set param as DateTime object?
    ->setParameter('todayStartDate', new DateTime("2011-08-01 00:00:00")->format("Y-m-d H:i:s"))

Comment: I've updated the query with `\DateTime` objects and have added a bit of text about the results. If I sort it to a single row per user result I will change my answer to include that.

Comment: getting this error `Error: Cannot use object of type PNC\LogBundle\Entity\LoginHistory as array` while using aggregation method?

Comment: 'logout case not working` well my friend, I var_dump the output, and in every case the `logout has null value`.

Comment: Have you copied and pasted exactly what is there or did you rewrite it? Upload the code you are currently using to your question and I can see what's going on. Also are you sure that there are logout events in your data?